# MySQL remote hosted on virtual Server - can't connect from Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, windows-server-2008, remote-access

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL Server hosted on a virtual Server running IIS.  I have granted to all ips to root using the

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

I am able to connect from another Windows machine by going to the ip address that I use to remote in but I can not connect from a mac on another network...
I can remote to the computer's ip from other networks but not luck with MySQL.

The firewall has also been disabled.

Comment: What error do you get when this fails? From what software are you attempting to connect?

Comment: Are you able to ping the machines on the network where the sql server is from the network where your mac is?

Comment: @ollie jones sqlworkbench - get basic can't connect error

Comment: @TJ I can ping the machines on the network from other machines on the network but not from machines on another network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like there is no Internet Protocol route from your mac to the server machine that's running MySQL.

If you cannot use `ping` on your mac to get a response from your server machine, you will not be able to connect from your machine to MySQL on that server.

You may need to consult with your network engineering team to get them to figure this out for you.

Comment: I am going to run some tests on a windows machine on another network and see if it is failing there too.

Comment: able to connect via another machine on another separate network ...the issue now must be osx...any ideas?

Comment: you are correct it was a route issue blocked by engineering...thank you for the help, sorry if i wasted your time